Oracle Scheduler Job Failing
I submitted a scheduler job in Oracle to run at a specific time daily. However, when I checked today, the job had failed as indicated in USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS. Where can I find the reason for its failure? Additionally, I couldn't find clear information about checking if scheduling is enabled in a controlled environment. Any guidance on how to determine whether scheduling is enabled would also be appreciated.
Scheduled job should run at the time and should have given errors in the control table that i created for job tracking but the job didn't even start

If your job is failing to run, you wont have any data in your custom log table, thats obvious.
There is a view for that called USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG or ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG depending where you have defined your job. You can check there whetever job failed or successfully ended.
You can filter the data by your job name, for example:
SELECT * FROM USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG
WHERE JOB_NAME = 'JOB_NAME';

If you need a reason you need to use view called USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILSor USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS.

thanks, got the reason of failure from user_scheduler_job_run_details.
